Using Poisson distribution when constructing GLM in R with non-integer dependent variable. Using offset
I am having trouble building a GLM model using the Poisson distribution. I am studying the effect of variables on the number of birds (4 variables in total). My dependent variable "density" has non-integer numbers and an error occurs. I do not want to round the numbers, and I do not want to use quasi-Poisson.
Example<-structure(list(birds = c(9L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 
5L, 2L), area = c(3.55, 2.52, 1.49, 1, 1.13, 1.49, 1.4, 0.57, 
1.11, 1.78, 1.63), density = c(2.5, 0.8, 1.3, 4, 0.9, 0.7, 2.9, 
1.8, 4.5, 2.8, 1.2), green = c(5.95, 5.62, 6.32, 6.04, 4.91, 
5.36, 7.15, 5.22, 6.8, 6.69, 6.47), open = c(3.69, 5, 3.94, 4.05, 
3.48, 3.97, 4.12, 4.29, 4.29, 3.56, 4), distance = c(0.6, 3, 
1, 0.9, 1, 1, 2.5, 3.2, 3.8, 2.5, 3), human = c(21.29, 22.76, 
23.02, 20.88, 21.26, 21.87, 23.19, 21.82, 19.49, 21.68, 19.6)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))

fix(Example) # data table

I read that in such cases log is used as an offset and added new columns "birds" and "area" to the table, taking into account that density = birds / area.
I used the following code:
model = glm (birds ~ green + human + distance + open + offset (log (area)),
data = Example, family = poisson (link = "log"))

After manually building all possible models, I began to doubt the results of the obtained data. The model with the least influential factor "open" was in the top 3 models, which is an artifact. I compared the models using compareGLM, using AICc values for small samples.
compareGLM(model.1, model.2, model.3, model.4, model.5, model.6, model.7, model.8, model.9, model.10, model.11, model.12, model.13, model.14, model.15)

$Models
   Formula                                                     
1  "birds ~ green + human + distance + open + offset(log(area))"
2  "birds ~ green + human + distance + offset(log(area))"       
3  "birds ~ green + human + offset(log(area))"                  
4  "birds ~ green + offset(log(area))"                          
5  "birds ~ human + offset(log(area))"                          
6  "birds ~ distance + offset(log(area))"                       
7  "birds ~ human + distance + offset(log(area))"               
8  "birds ~ open + offset(log(area))"                           
9  "birds ~ green + open + offset(log(area))"                   
10 "birds ~ green + distance + offset(log(area))"               
11 "birds ~ open + distance + offset(log(area))"                
12 "birds ~ open + human + offset(log(area))"                   
13 "birds ~ green + open + distance + offset(log(area))"        
14 "birds ~ green + open + human + offset(log(area))"           
15 "birds ~ open + distance + human + offset(log(area))"        

$Fit.criteria
   Rank Df.res   AIC  AICc   BIC McFadden Cox.and.Snell Nagelkerke p.value
1     5      6 48.17 69.17 50.55   0.2506        0.6669     0.6753 0.05776
2     4      7 46.23 58.23 48.22   0.2493        0.6651     0.6735 0.03640
3     3      8 45.53 52.20 47.13   0.2222        0.6228     0.6306 0.03394
4     2      9 44.58 48.01 45.77   0.2006        0.5852     0.5925 0.02195
5     2      9 47.41 50.84 48.61   0.1419        0.4634     0.4692 0.15350
6     2      9 48.88 52.31 50.07   0.1115        0.3869     0.3918 2.02200
7     3      8 49.41 56.07 51.00   0.1420        0.4636     0.4694 0.23540
8     2      9 48.02 51.45 49.22   0.1292        0.4327     0.4382 0.27070
9     3      8 45.98 52.65 47.57   0.2130        0.6073     0.6149 0.04238
10    3      8 46.03 52.69 47.62   0.2120        0.6055     0.6132 0.04340
11    3      8 49.21 55.88 50.80   0.1460        0.4731     0.4790 0.21340
12    3      8 48.97 55.64 50.57   0.1510        0.4843     0.4904 0.18950
13    4      7 47.87 59.87 49.86   0.2153        0.6112     0.6189 0.07186
14    4      7 47.13 59.13 49.12   0.2307        0.6365     0.6445 0.05315
15    4      7 50.72 62.72 52.71   0.1562        0.4961     0.5024 0.19730

What am I doing wrong using offset? Are there other ways to apply Poisson distribution to non-integer values of the dependent variable?
Thanks in advance.
